# JS – Reload script when resizing viewport

Tags: javascript, css

I have a dynamic HTML element which has a height set in percent and a width equal to the height. – The height changes, depending on the viewport size and I always have to obtain a 1:1 aspect ratio, which is why I use a scrip, on page load, to look at the height and make that the width too.

So when I open the site, everything looks like it should, but as soon, as I resize it, the height value of course changes and the width stays the same.

**Is there a way so that I can make it, that my scrip reloads, when the viewport changes size?**

Comment: Javascript works in an infinite loop of events. Take interest in events and find the right one. Maybe onresize? https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp

Comment: @SlawomirDziuba Thank you, I will look into this. – Still very new to JS. Regards- Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<body onresize="myFunction()">
```

…solves the Problem. – I just made my script into a function an added onresize to the body.

Credit to: [w3schools – onresize Event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onresize.asp) and @SlawomirDziuba for pointing this out to me.

Edit:

As @SlawomirDziuba pointed out, you can also use:

```
window.addEventListener ('resize', myFunction);
```

Doing it like that allows you to have all your JS at one place.

Comment: It will make more sense to use js only in the js file and use: window.addEventListener ('resize', myFunction); Note the lack of parentheses () after myFunction. You don't call it, you assign it.

Comment: @SlawomirDziuba Thank you! – This feels like a more elegant solution. :)